# syncing SQL SERVER and Android SQLite

Tags: android, sql-server, android-sqlite

I have a database on SQL server which is local. I can sync those data with the sqlite database  of my android app.
I am syncing those database by counting the rows of tables in both databases.
But the problem is, when the data is updated from the server itself or from the desktop application, how to update that specific data into sqlite.... 
I am using MSSQL SERVER 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try either...

1. Use [GCM](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) to notify the change

OR

1. Add one more table in your database to log the changes.. fields[log_id,table,table_data_id,operation(update or delete)] and save all update and delete logs in this table.
2. Create an api file to return the log from server... accept a GET patrameter log_id ... then query logs greater than requested log_id id
3. Then in Android create a shared preference to keep the log_id
4. While opening the app request to the api using the current log_id or zero if no log_id
5. Then do the operation followed by the api response.. after complete all the operation update the shared preference with the last log_id
6. Using this way you can identify the changes made in server and update in sqlite